# Exclude certain views from dimming with UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit

When presenting a UIAlertController, it dims the whole screen. Is there a way to exclude a certain view from being dimmed?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. **No**.

Why?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be **modified**.

**Emphasis mine.**

So what do you do now?

You can roll your own version, or search for available libraries that do so.